# Excel VBA suddenly doesn't recognize non-declared variables and some functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, azure

We recently had one of our servers migrated to Azure with a Bastion VM connection.

A number of macro based Excel workbooks sit on the server and have stopped functioning as they used to. I'm getting piles of compile errors.

A number of the issues seen are:

1. All variables now need to be declared when previously they haven't been (it's a poor practice I know) even with Option Explicit not set and the checkbox clear in Options.
2. Macros will no longer call on subs from other open workbooks.
3. Some functions need to be prefixed with VBA. where not needed previously.

I'm at a loss to understand what has changed and not enjoying the tedious stepping through the VBA to fix each individual error.

Short of going back to the 90s and 00s and explaining to the original developers of these spreadsheets that Excel is not the best platform for building applications (they is exactly what they tried to do) any ideas on what has caused this and is there an easy fix?

Comment: You're probably missing a pre-requisite, like a redist that was on the old server. Have you made sure you installed all the runtimes that were present on the old server?

Comment: Check if in the Visual Basic Editor, menu *Tools > Options*, Editor tab, if the option "Require Variable Declaration" is set.